# MikroORM jest unit test - how to provide entity repository with connect: false

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, ts-jest, mikro-orm

When I use `MikroORM.init()` in unit test I want to use `connect:false` option to not create db connection, but test the entity behaviour for example more complex update method like: **"`wrap(existingCook).assign(`updateCookDto`);`"**

**important I don't want to mock functions from  entity repository or connect to real db.**

My setup:
Nestjs + MikroORM version: 5.5.3

**cook.entity.ts**

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey } from '@mikro-orm/core';

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

import { Cook } from '../../../domain';

@Entity({ tableName: 'cook' })
export class CookEntity implements Cook {
@PrimaryKey()
id: string = uuid();
}
```

**cook.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { EntityRepository } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { InjectRepository } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';

import { Cook } from '../../domain';

import { CookEntity } from './entities';

@Injectable()
export class CookService {
constructor(@InjectRepository(CookEntity) private readonly \_cookRepository: EntityRepository\<CookEntity\>) {}

    async findAll(): Promise<Array<Cook>> {
        return this._cookRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**cook.service.spec.ts**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CookService } from './cook.service';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { CookEntity } from './entities';
import { EntityRepository, MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/postgresql';

const config = defineConfig({
  connect: false,
  type: 'postgresql',
  dbName: 'cook',
  schema: 'cook',
  debug: true,
  entities: [CookEntity],
});

describe('CookService', () =\> {
let orm: MikroORM;
let cookRepository: EntityRepository\<CookEntity\>;

    let service: CookService;
    let testingModule: TestingModule;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        orm = await MikroORM.init(config);
        cookRepository = orm.em.getRepository(CookEntity);
    
        testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                CookService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(CookEntity),
                    useValue: cookRepository,
                },
            ],
        }).compile();
    
        service = testingModule.get<CookService>(CookService);
    });
    
    it('should be defined', async () => {
        // Then
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    
        await service.findAll();
    });

});
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should let the nest DI create the ORM instance, you should alter the config the nest DI uses, that way the context should be set up correctly.

The way you do it now literally uses the global ORM instance, so the validation error is correct. On the other hand, if you won't be reusing this ORM instance across multiple tests, it should be fine to just disable the validation, either with the `allowGlobalContext` option, or simply by forking the EM:

```
orm = await MikroORM.init(config);
cookRepository = orm.em.fork().getRepository(CookEntity); // <-- fork first
    
testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
        CookService,
        {
            provide: getRepositoryToken(CookEntity),
            useValue: cookRepository,
        },
    ],
}).compile();
```

Note that the explicit forking this way will work, but only if you don't use other repositories or the EM directly, so the `allowGlobalContext` is preferrable here.

Comment: Thank You @Martin for Your time. After adding this line `cookRepository = orm.em.fork().getRepository(CookEntity);` and setting `allowGlobalContext: true` I get new error: **DriverException: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'queryBuilder')**

Comment: this should be already resolved in latest version, definitely in v6, not sure if in v5. the error is (probably) caused by not having knex initialized. whats the full stack trace?

Comment: Ok @Martin soo I'v updated to latest version v6.0.0-dev.91.
Here is the paste bin https://pastebin.com/NG6EfjY4 with updated test matching v.6 version and used package.json

Now have new error: **DriverException: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432**

It seams like it's trying to connect to db even if the `connect:false` option is set.

Comment: it connects lazily if you use something that needs db connection. dont expect you can work with the query builder without a connection.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer.
Soo whats the real case with this `connect:false` option ?
Is there any other option to achieve my testing scenario other than connecting to real data base ?
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: working with the entities might require the ORM to be initialized, namely when you try to add or remove things from a 1:m/m:n collection, as that requires the metadata to be present (for propagation to work). its probably the very same issue you faced when trying to use `assign`, as that under the hood acts as if you would manipulate the properties explicitly.

Comment: so for working with entities this will be enough, but it wont help when you want to use some repository methods like `findAll` (or generally anything that queries the database). for that you either need the database or mock the methods.

Comment: there is one more alternative, you could also consider using a different driver for testing, namely sqlite in memory database is an interesting candidate for unit tests. i would personally discourage this, as each dialect behaves a bit differently, and has a different set of features (e.g. generating uuid on db level). but if you only rely on basic features SQL, it might be fine.